# Random walk simulation based on the flipping of a biased coin 100 times

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, simulation, random-walk, coin-flipping

I'm starting in Python. I'm trying to make a simulation of a random walk in a straight line (north and south) based on flipping a biased coin 100 times with 0.3 chance of getting tails and 0.7 chance of getting heads assuming that the values from the starting point to the south are negative and from the starting point to the north are positive.

I tried two different things but they don't work properly.

```
import random
def prob(p):
return random.random()<p
def random_walk(n):
heads=0
tails=0
t=0
for i in range(n):
    if prob(0.3):
        heads += 1
        t=t-1
    if prob (0.7):
        tails += 1
        t=t+1
print (heads, "heads")
print (tails, "tails")
print (t)
return t

heads=0
tails=0
t=0
for i in range(0,100):
    if prob(0.3):
        heads += 1
        t=t-1
    if prob(0.7):
        tails += 1
        t=t+1
print (heads, "heads")
print (tails, "tails")
print (t)
```

Comment: Hi, can you be more specific about "not working properly", what is the unexpected behaviour that you find? Please explain! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is with your calls to the `prob` function. Since you call the function twice within each iteration of your `for i in range(n)` loop, you end up with two different RNs.

Also, if `random.random()` returns, say, `0.1` and `0.2`, then both if blocks associated with `if prob(0.3):` and `if prob(0.7):` will execute in the same simulation loop.

You need to call `random.random()` a single time per execution loop, and make both if statements mutually exclusive - changing it to a if/else block, for example.

Here's a way to fix these issues:

```
for i in range(n):
    coin_has_flipped_tails = prob(0.3)
    if coin_has_flipped_tails:
        tails += 1
        t += 1
    else:  # this implies that the coin has flipped head
        heads += 1
        t -= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is not flipping coin 100 times, but 200 times!

Every call to the `prob()` function is a coin flip. Now every iteration of the `for` cycle contains 2 calls - first with 0.3, later with 0.7.

what you are looking for may be something like

```
for _ in range(n):
  if prob(0.3):
    heads +=1
  else:
    tails +=1
```

This way, you make exactly 100 tosses (prob calls), and each and every one of them is either head, or tail.